# Why does an SVN server at projectlocker.com have 3 addresses?

Tags: svn

I started a repository  at projectlocker.com. They gave me 3 url addresses. A subversion URL, a subversion server, and a subversion root.

Why are there 3 addresses? I uploaded to the subversion URL and it seems to work. Is this the same url that people others download from? When should I use the other addresses?

Comment: Have you tried to open those urls? ;-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I tried it myself. On which page do you see the subversion URL, the subversion server URL and the subversion root? I see only a subversion URL and a Trac SVN browser URL and a Trac (wiki) URL.

Comment: It was on this popup page about getting setup. https://portal.projectlocker.com/help/setup?project=147790&service=SVN

Answer (score 1):

Could you list the addresses (with fake servername etc.) so we can see?

The subversion URL might be the address to the subversion server + the root of you project.

If that is the case and you only have one project, then you just need the one you used.

Is this the case?

```
svn://example server name/example project

svn://example server name/

example project
```